# How to access values in a class?

Tags: python, function, class, nameerror

I've made a class from which I want to access some values. This is what the class looks like:

```
class County:
  def __init__(self, init_name, init_population, init_voters) :
    self.name = init_name
    self.population = init_population
    self.voters = init_voters
```

there is another function that I want to implement.

```
def highest_turnout(data) :
    turnout = (self.voters / self.population) / 100

    return #I haven't completed what I need to do
```

since I want to access values from function 1, I put the second function within that class to access these values. However, I started getting a NameError further down the code.

```
result = highest_turnout(data) #this is the name of my function
#this is the error I get
NameError: name 'highest_turnout' is not defined
```

so my question is, do I really need to put the second function in the class in order to access the values? If I need to, then why am I getting this error and how can I fix it?

Comment: `County(....data...).highest_turnout(data)` ?

Answer (score 1):

Let's say we have this class.

```
class County:
    def __init__(self, init_name, init_population, init_voters):
        self.name = init_name
        self.population = init_population
        self.voters = init_voters
```

Then we construct a value of it as follows.

```
data = Country(...)
```

Now, the instance's name is `self` inside of the class (idiomatically, at least), so if you have an instance method *on the class*, you use `self` to refer to it. But if you define a standalone function which takes an argument called `data`, then you use `data` to refer to it, not `self`, as such.

```
# NOT in the class
def highest_turnout(data):
    turnout = (data.voters / data.population) / 100

highest_turnout(data)
```

If you *do* want it to be in the class, then you do so as follows.

```
# In the class
def highest_turnout(self):
    turnout = (self.voters / self.population) / 100

data.highest_turnout()
```

Comment: I put the second function outside the class but I get this error: AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'voters'

Answer (score 1):

you have to add `self` as parameter to your method in order to access class fields, it also has to be on same indentation level as your class constructor like this:

```
class County:
  def __init__(self, name, population, voters) :
    self.name = name
    self.population = population
    self.voters = voters

  def highest_turnout(self, data) :
    turnout = (self.voters / self.population) / 100

    return #I haven't completed what I need to do
```

alos who told you to prefix all parameters in init function with `init_` thats useles